# Questions about Mongoose Schema design

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

I'm completely new to the NoSQL world and it's been difficult to wrap my mind around it. This week I was learning MongoDB (Mongoose) with Node.js and here is my current schema:

```
var eventDataSchema = new Schema({
  _id        : Number,
  notes      : {type: String, required: true},
  start_date : {type: Date, required: true},
  end_date   : {type: Date, required: true},
},  {
  id         : false,
  collection : 'event-data'
});
eventDataSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement);

var EventData = mongoose.model('EventData', eventDataSchema);
```

Now that this is working, I would like to add a user and password and have access to have personal access to `EventData`.

Also... later if I want to send a JSON of only the eventData, but not the user to my javascript, how would I do that?

The way I am currently sending my eventData to my js in this format:

```
router.get('/data', function(req, res){
  EventData.find({}, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error occured');
    }
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

Thanks again

Comment: Can you please be more specific ?

Comment: Sure... I want to implement in this schema an user and password to use for authentication, but inside this schema, I want also to have many blocks of eventData. Example: 
user: John Doe
password: 123
  events: [ { _id: 1
notes: Event A
start_date: 1/1/01,
end_date: 1/1/01,
},
{ _id: 2
notes: Event B
start_date: 1/2/01,
end_date: 1/2/01,
},
{ _id: 3
notes: Event C
start_date: 1/3/01,
end_date: 1/3/01,
}]

Comment: John Doe would sign up and have access to his events A, B and C. While there might be another user with a different collection of events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can understand you want to add events key in your schema. Then your schema will be like that:

```
    var userSchema = new Schema({
        user: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        events: [{ 
             notes: { type: String,required: true, trim: true },
             start_date: { type: Date,required: true },
             end_date: { type: Date,required: true } 
            }]
    }
    userSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement);
    var userSchema = mongoose.model('userSchema', userSchema);
 });
```

**If the above code is not working then you can create two schema,one for user and other for eventData, and can populate your eventData in userSchema.**

so your code will be like that:

**userSchema.js:**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
        user: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        events: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'EventData' }

    userSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement);
    module.exports = mongoose.model('userSchema', userSchema);
});
```

And your **eventDataSchema** will be:

**eventSchema.js:**

```
    var eventDataSchema = new Schema({
             notes: { type: 'string',required: true, trim: true },
             start_date: { type: Date,required: true },
             end_date: { type: Date,required: true } 
    }
    eventDataSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement);
    module.exports = mongoose.model('EventData', eventDataSchema);
 });
```

and then you can get the result like that:
index.js:

```
var eventSchema = require('./eventSchema');
var userSchema = require('./userSchema');

var populate = [{
        path: 'events',
        model: 'EventData',
        select: '_id notes start_dat end_date'
    }];

var find = function (query) {
    return userSchema.find(query).populate(populate).exec();
}
console.log(find());
```

**Result:**

```
{
      _id:cfgvhbjnkmkdcfxghgjklxnmbxhdhjxjhjhgx,
      user: John Doe,
      password: 123,
      events: [ { _id: 1gfye56785g3ycgevhxeftx568765egcd,
                  notes: Event A,
                  start_date: 1/1/01, 
                  end_date: 1/1/01
                } ]

}
```

Comment: thanks good sir. That is what I was struggling to understand, but seeing your example, it makes more sense now.

Comment: Welcome@user258813